# Spring configuration org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' is defined

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I thought this is no-brainier but running into this rut. Unable to understand why is this happening.
this is how my servlet-context.xml looks like

```
<beans:bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <beans:property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" id="entityManagerFactory">
    <beans:property name="persistenceUnitName" value="xxxx"/>
     <beans:property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml"/>
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</beans:bean>
```

and corresponding web.xml file to over come problem with lazy initialization

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>SpringOpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-class>
     <init-param>
        <param-name>entityManagerFactoryBeanName</param-name>
        <param-value>entityManagerFactory</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>SpringOpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

but I am running into exception as soon as I try to access my application with following exception trace

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' is defined
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:638)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1159)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:282)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:979)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.lookupEntityManagerFactory(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:187)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.lookupEntityManagerFactory(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:170)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:128)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
```

Any idea what I am missing in this.

Answer (score 0):

All your configurations are fine. Except for the fact that you are missing the org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor in your spring bean configuration xml file. Just try including that and see if it works. But I haven't used it though.

If you are facing the problem of lazy loading and want to resolve that, I would suggest you demarcate @Transaction in the methods where you would use the lazy collection/lazy loaded object (typically in the service layer) rather than placing this on the DAO class's methods. That way you can get the transaction to be a little prolonging.

Comment: I tried marking @Transaction in the controller layer it self to see if that fix the issue, but that is not helping me, unless I change fetch mode to EAGER, which is not I would like to do. Any idea what else can be tried.

Comment: When marking transactions in controller layer have you taken out the OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter and let Spring manage the transaction for you. The purpose of this filter is only to access the managed entities and its lazy loaded objects in web views even if the underlying transaction gets committed.